# Configure JDBC and Hibernate Together in Spring

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring, jdbc

We have multiple war files packaged in an ear file. Some of the wars are using pure JDBC and we want to use hibernate for new wars (modules). We are using spring 2.5.6, hibernate 3.0 and jboss 4.2 server. We have following configuration for transactionmanager.

```
<bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
        <property name="jndiName" value="java:MyPool" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager">
        <property name="allowCustomIsolationLevels">
            <value>true</value>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

It is working fine for us.

Now I want to configure hibernate transactionManger for new modules in a separate xml file.

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>  
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
  </bean>
```

Generally we configure hiberanate transaction mangager in following way.

```
<bean id="transactionManager"   class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
  </bean>
```

But I would like to use same JtaTransactionManager reference defined for JDBC configuration. Please help me in configuring this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not really need JTA if you are not using 2 phase commits. Just configure Hibernate trans mgr and it is capable of handling both hibernate and jdbc transactions. This link might also be helpful http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=69864